# vee validate "required" validation is working only when on change of the field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Below is my code. Three fields are there in my form. Firstname, Middlename, Lastname. All these fields are set as required one. Only difference is that "Firstname & Lastname" contains input tag, but "Middlename" contains b-form-input tag. Actually my problem is, When I focus out(blur) these("Firstname & Lastname") fields it throws an required error but when I do the same for ("Middlename") field it doesn't [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUTUN.png). I have to enter the value in that ("Middlename") field [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVum.png) ,then I removed the value it's throwing error
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19DFB.png) i.e. required validation is only working "on change" of the "("Middlename") field. What is the reason for this?

```
<template>
 <b-card>
    <h4 slot="header" class="card-title">Employee</h4>
        <b-row>
            <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">First Name </label>
                <input type="text" id=""  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required'" name="Firstname">
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Firstname')" class="is-danger">{{ errors.first('Firstname') }}</span>
               </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Middle Name </label>
                <b-form-input type="text" id=""  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" v-validate="'required'" name="Middlename"> </b-form-input>
                  <span v-show="errors.has('Middlename')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Middlename') }}</span>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
             <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label for="name">Last Name </label>
                <input type="text" id=""  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your middle name" v-validate="'required|Name'" name="Lastname">
                        <span v-show="errors.has('Lastname')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('Lastname') }}</span>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" @click="validateForm">
 </b-card>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
  name: 'addEmpl',
   created: function() {
    this.$validator.extend('Name', {
    getMessage: field => '* Enter valid ' + field + '',
    validate: value => /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value)
    });
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I am also new to Vue.js and Vee-validate so I stand corrected.

The difference between the 2 fields and the middlename field is that it is a component instead of native input field.

In essence, you need to make the component behaves like an input, i.e. emits the necessary events so Vee-validate can pick up on them ('input', 'change', **'blur'** etc).

For e.g if your component  is a div wrapping on input it would be something like this:

```
<template>
   <div class="myClassForDiv">
      <input 
         type="text"
         class="myClass"
         @blur="$emit('blur')"
         @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      >
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: "b-form-input"
   }
</script>
```

The part relevant to the question is `@blur="$emit('blur')"`. Without this line, VeeValidate has no way of getting notified of a blur event occurring hence does not validate (I don't know what other events VeeValidate listens to by default, but 'blur' works for me and 'focusout' does not. You can always use the `data-vv-validate-on` directive for special events specific to your components).

You may refer to the this article by the maintainer of VeeValidate library. Notice how he creates a component that plays nicely with VeeValidate by making the component emits all the right events.

https://medium.com/@logaretm/authoring-validatable-custom-vue-input-components-1583fcc68314